# How can I write multiple level log message with log4j? (for example both INFO and ERROR)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, log4j

I am absolutly new in **log4j** and I have the following doubt.

I have this configuration that write into a file all the **info** level log definied into my application code:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
#log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out
#log4j.appender.FILE.File=C:/Projects/edi-sta/build/jar/mytest.log
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

My doubt is: what can I do if in addition to logging the **INFO** level log I want to write in the file also the **ERROR** level log (or some other debug level message)?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **INFO** level should automatically include **ERROR** and **CRITICAL** levels etc.

You just need to set logging level to **ERROR** for root to print above **ERROR** only.

You can also set various log levels for classes in specific packages viz.

```
log4j.logger.com.mycompany.controller = DEBUG

log4j.logger.com.mycompany.service = INFO

log4j.logger.com.mycompany.repo = ERROR
```